# How to delete all files in a directory except some globs using Puppet?

Tags: puppet

Spell checkers unfortunately don't come packaged for regions, so after [installing English, French and German dictionaries](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/94ce5942f1a6e2959b41211409f3d7b644a04b74/modules/spell_checker/manifests/init.pp#L7) I get this huge collection:

```
$ find /usr/share/myspell/dicts/ -name '*.dic' | cut -d '/' -f 6 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sort
de_AT
de_BE
de_CH
de_DE
de_LI
de_LU
en_AG
en_AU
en_BS
en_BW
en_BZ
en_CA
en_DK
en_GB
en_GH
en_HK
en_IE
en_IN
en_JM
en_NA
en_NG
en_NZ
en_PH
en_SG
en_TT
en_US
en_ZA
en_ZW
fr_BE
fr_CA
fr_CH
fr_FR
fr_LU
```

English as spoken in *Denmark*, where it's not even an official language? Anyway, I'd like to keep `de_CH*`, `de_DE*`, `en_GB*`, `en_US*`, and `fr_FR*`, and delete all other files. Is there a way to achieve that using Puppet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it [looks like this is a solved problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/388244/puppet-exclude-file-from-management-for-managed-directory). [Solution](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/be0c39fa364763f193c1de4e28b1d78b9bee130f/modules/spell_checker/manifests/init.pp#L13-L27):

```
class spell_checker {
  package {
    [
      'aspell-de',
      'aspell-en',
      'aspell-fr',
      'hunspell-de',
      'hunspell-en',
      'hunspell-fr',
    ]:
      ensure => latest,
  }->
  file{
    [
      '/usr/share/hunspell',
      '/usr/share/myspell/dicts',
    ]:
    recurse => true,
    purge   => true,
    ignore  => [
      'de_CH.*',
      'de_DE.*',
      'en_GB.*',
      'en_US.*',
      'fr_FR.*',
    ],
  }
}
```

End result:

```
$ find /usr/share/myspell/dicts/ -name '*.dic' | cut -d '/' -f 6 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sort
de_CH
de_DE
en_GB
en_US
fr_FR
```