# How to list available dictionaries for hunspell?

Tags: spell-checking, dictionary, hunspell

Is there some way to list all available dictionaries in `hunspell`? Something like `aspell dump dicts`. `printf | hunspell -D` prints too much junk, and I want to query `hunspell` itself, not do something like [`find /usr/share/myspell/dicts/ -name '*.dic' | cut -d '/' -f 6 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sort`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187355/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some-globs-using-puppet).

Comment: You could look into [pyenchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/), e.g. a basic example: `python -c 'import enchant;print(*enchant.list_dicts(), sep="\n")'`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
LANG=C </dev/null hunspell -D|&sed -n '/AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES/,/LOADED DICTIONARIES/p'|awk -F / '/\// { print $NF }'|sort -u
```

This drops the `hunspell` search path from the output and lists only available dictionary names. If you want to remove hyphenation dictionaires you can add `|grep -v hyph`...

Comment: Nice, but this gets a bit kludgy if you want it to be reliable: It needs an `echo |` at the start to terminate the input stream, it should handle the case of no dictionaries (Is there a heading in that case?) or a single dictionary (Is that heading singular?), and it needs to stop before the `LOADED DICTIONARY` line if it exists (or EOF if it doesn't).

Comment: Looking at the source code, there always is an "AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES" heading even if no dictionaries are installed, and it doesn't change for a single dictionary; but it is locale-dependent. I'll update my answer accordingly (and with `< /dev/null` to handle the input stream).